# alternatives to adding entry in /etc/hosts

Tags: networking

I would like to access a remote host using a short name. On a system where I have admin rights, I would achieve this by adding an entry in `/etc/hosts` file, something like this

`121.121.122.1  shortname`

Is it possible to achieve this using some other method which does not require modifying /etc/hosts or other admin level or system wide changes?

Comment: Depends on why you want to create aliases.  If its because you want to SSH to the short-name, you can use the Host and HostName configuration options in your SSH config.  Maybe if your more specific about what you're trying to accomplish, you'll get some more useful feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should lookup your local-network-name. Most routers seem to set some kind of hostname-system. a fritzbox uses `hostname.fritz.box` for example, a thompson device uses `hostname.lan`, and its not unlikely your router has something to offer as well.

I take it you dont have access to the routers interface to set a DNS record? That would be the easiest way to accomplish it totally to your guidelines